# C-u instead of M- when I press ALT key

Tags: keymap

When I press the `ALT` key (in specific `ALT-0`) it turns out to be `C-u` (`C-u 0`) instead of `M-` (`M-0`). I am using Windows 10. What is the problem and the solution?

Comment: Well, what _is_ the problem? Some keybindings are equivalent to each other. In terminals, `C-i` is the same as `TAB` and `C-m` is the same as `RET`. Meta-5 in emacs tells it to run the folling command 5 times, this is a feature. The main question is: what do you want to do and how is this keeping you from doing it?

Comment: `C-h k M-0` will show you that it is bound to `digit-argument`.

Comment: @Kaligule I said that when I press the ALT key it turns out to be C-u, not M-. So it is clear that I want M- when I press ALT key, not C-u.

Comment: @efe373 You do *not* get `C-u` when you press ALT -- not in this or any other scenario.  As has already been explained, `M-0` and other Meta-modified digits are bound to `digit-argument`.  It's just a key binding, like any other (and it's not even the *same* key binding as `C-u` which is bound to `universal-argument`, although they are very closely related).  Your ALT key is still the Meta modifier as always.

Comment: Down-voted due to lack of follow-up/clarification of the problem, to prevent this question from being auto-bumped to the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what you really want to do, but Emacs makes `M-0` do the same thing as `C-u 0` and this is quite a deliberate design choice. They both put you into a mode where you can type in a numeric prefix which will be applied to the next command. Some commands treat their prefix in a unique way, but most just get repeated that many times. For example, if you wanted to go down 11 lines you could press the down arrow 11 times or you could press `M-1 1 <down>`, which is a lot fewer keystrokes. You could also type `C-u 1 1 <down>`, which is pretty good at just one extra keystroke. Whichever makes you happiest.

These keys are not actually identical the way that `TAB` and `C-i` are inside of a terminal, so you can still bind some other function to `M-0` if you want. You do that in exactly the same way as you would bind any other key:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-0") 'your-preferred-keybinding)
```

Just be aware that you are overriding a built–in feature and that you might want it back some day.